# Async Oracle Driver for .NET

Tags: database, .net

I am looking for an async capable (using the async/await features) .NET client that can connect to Oracle 10GR2 and higher databases. Free and open source is preferred, but other suggestions are welcome.

- Async capable (async/await)
- .NET Framework
- Oracle 10GR2 and above

The Oracle provided ODP.NET library isn't actual async, it's synchronous code wrapped in async. Which means it has all of the disadvantages of async code with none of the advantages. Support for that assertion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016698/can-the-oracle-managed-driver-use-async-wait-properly/29034412#29034412) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544557/async-i-o-intensive-code-is-running-slower-than-non-async-why).